# Query to select the highest and lowest values for a given day?

Tags: grafana

I would like to compose a query such that the highest (max) and lowest (min) values for each day are selected. Here is my current query:

```
SELECT
  min("value"),
  max("value")
FROM
  "temperature"
WHERE
  $timeFilter
GROUP BY
  time(1d)
  fill(null)
```

[image]

This query does select the minimum and maximum value for each 24-hour period but that period begins at 17:00 local time. My intent is to have each period begin at 0:00 local time.

How do I specify the "offset" for the query?

Comment: do by any chance were you able to do it ? (3 years ago, I know)

Answer (score 0):

Grafana by default applies the timezone from your browser settings. I guess your timezone is UTC-7. You can set the timezone to UTC in the dashboard settings to get it to align.

[image]